Spectrum of operator in $l^2$ equals closure of $\{b_k : k \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$
I'm trying to understand why, in the following example,
the spectrum of T includes limit points.

Let $b_k \rightarrow l$, yet $(T-l \cdot I )(a) = (a_1(b_1-l)\cdots, a_k (b_k-l), \cdots )$.
Since $\forall_k (b_k-l)\neq 0$, we can define $(T-l \cdot I )^{-1}(a)= \left(\frac{a_k}{b_k-l}\right)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}⁺}$, which make the sp(T) not being closed.
I must be doing something wrong. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the closure in the field $\mathbf{F}$.

Hint: If $b_k \to l$, is your “inverse” $(a_k) \mapsto (\frac{a_k}{b_k - l})$ actually defined everywhere and bounded?

ah... it's not bounded. @DavidGao thanks ;)

Indeed. It is also not everywhere defined, in the sense that there are $(a_k) \in l^2$ such that $(\frac{a_k}{b_k - l})$ is not in $l^2$ at all.

Here are a few ways to view this. One is to note that the spectrum of a bounded linear operator is always a compact, and consequently closed, subset of the given field. As a closed subset contains all of its limit points, the spectrum of $T$ contains all of its limit points.
A second way is analogous to your attempted proof that limit points are in the spectrum of $T$. Suppose for a contradiction that there is $\lambda \in \overline{\{b_{k} : k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\}} \setminus \{b_{k} : k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$ such that $T-\lambda I$ has an inverse $S$. Let $(e_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ denote the standard orthonormal basis on $\ell_{2}$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the calculation $e_{n} = S((T-\lambda I)(e_{n})) = (b_{n} - \lambda )S(e_{n})$ shows that $S(e_{n}) = (b_{n} - \lambda )^{-1}e_{n}$. As a result, if $B_{\ell_{2}}$ denotes the closed unit ball of $\ell_{2}$, the set $\{\|S(x)\| : x\in B_{\ell_{2}} \}$ is unbounded because the set $\{(b_{n} - \lambda )^{-1} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is unbounded, which shows that $S$ is not a bounded linear operator. But as it was assumed that $T-\lambda I$ is an invertible bounded linear operator, this contradicts bounded inverse theorem.
A third way is to note that if $X$ is a (non-trivial) Banach space and $A$ is an invertible bounded linear operator on $X$, then it follows from the bounded inverse theorem that $A$ is bounded below, which means that there exists $C>0$ such that $C\|x\| \leq \|A(x)\|$ for all $x\in X$. This implies that $\inf \{\|A(x)\| : x\in S_{X}\} > 0$, where $S_{X} = \{x\in X : \|x\| = 1\}$. By applying this to $T-\lambda I$ for a given $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$, it follows that if $\inf\{\|(T-\lambda I)(x)\| : x\in S_{\ell_{2}} \} =0$, then $T-\lambda I$ is not an invertible bounded linear operator and $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of $T$. If $\lambda \in \overline{\{b_{k} : k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\}}$, then as $(T-\lambda I)(e_{n}) = (b_{n} - \lambda )e_{n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\inf\{\|(T-\lambda I)(x)\| : x\in S_{\ell_{2}} \} \leq \inf\{\|(T-\lambda I)(e_{n})\| : n\in\mathbb{N} \} = \inf\{|b_{n} - \lambda | : n\in\mathbb{N} \} = 0$. This shows that $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of $T$.
